# ¿Existe en español un cognado para la voz inglesa "ship"?

Tags: vocabulario, false-cognate

En ingles, existen muchas palabras para designar distintos tipos de barcos. ¿Existe en español un [cognado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognado) de "ship"?

Answer (score 2):

Tel vez "[esquife](https://dle.rae.es/esquife)", although it refers to a very specific kind of ship:

> Del cat. esquif, este del it. ant. schifo, y este del longobardo *skif; cf. a. al. ant. skif, ingl. ship.

> Barco pequeño que se lleva en el navío para saltar a tierra y para otros usos.

Also [here](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ship):

> French esquif, Italian schifo are Germanic loan-words.

Comment: It comes from skiff. Which is a boat not a ship.